# Using Capybara with Rspec view specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

According to [this](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-rspec) I think I should be able to use Capybara's [has_field?](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_field%3F-instance_method) matcher from within my Rspec view specs:

```
RSpec.describe "teams/edit", type: :view do
  let(:team) { FactoryGirl.create(:team, name: "Team") }

  it "renders the edit team form" do
    assign(:team, team)

    render

    expect(rendered).to has_field?("Name")
  end

end
```

The above fails with:

```
Failure/Error: expect(rendered).to has_field?("Name")
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `has_field?' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::TeamsEdit:0x007f9cd40c82a8>
```

I've added `require 'capybara/rails'` to my `spec_helper.rb` and `gem 'capybara'` is in my `Gemfile`. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capybara 2.5 rspec matchers are available by default in view specs.  If using a version prior to 2.5 you can add

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.include Capybara::RSpecMatchers, :type => :view
end
```

to your RSpec config.

You use these matchers as

```
expect(rendered).to have_field('Name')
```

Note the use of have_field not has_field?